# javascript picture.js - Moving grouped items around the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I basically have a rectangle with a PointText item overlayed on top of it. I currently have a working sample where I can move items around on the canvas by using sample code from the paperjs-v0.9.23\examples\Paperjs.org\HitTesting.html which has been really useful. However, I want to treat the rectangle and the text as one logical grouping to be moved around.

Please see the link below to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/svt9wa9f/6/

In the HitTesting.html example it has this within the onMouseDown event: `

```
if (hitResult) 
{
    path = hitResult.item;
    if (hitResult.type == 'segment') 
    {
        segment = hitResult.segment;
    } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') 
    {
        var location = hitResult.location;
        segment = path.insert(location.index + 1, event.point);
        path.smooth();
    }
}
```

`

I was hoping I could modify this to work with the groups, but it seems this type of hitesting doesn't work. Everytime I click within any object I just get the 'fill' type. So I was then thinking I would have to do a linear search through the array of groups performing a hittest just to see which item is within the group. Or a hashmap keyd on items, and the value as the group. But there must be an easier way?

Within the fiddle example, the group code is commented out because. When you first execute it you can't see the items, you have to hover the mouse pointer of the canvas to get them to appear. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Ideally, I just need to be able to move these groups around through drag events, and extend the code to be able to determine whilst dragging if I am over another grouping. But that is further down the line.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `paper.Path.Group` doesn't exist, it's just `paper.Group()`. Then, in your drag handler, `group` doesn't exist, change those with `this` and you'll be fine. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svt9wa9f/8/)

Comment: Kaiido, I can't thank you enough. You have really helped me out. Kindest regards